# Pyomo.dae - Solving a system of DAEs with Casadi solver

Tags: python, ode, pyomo

i am trying to solve a system of DAE using pyomo.
This is a toy example

```py
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.dae import *

m = ConcreteModel()

m.r = ContinuousSet(bounds = (0., 1.))
m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds = (0., 5.))
m.c = Var(m.r, m.t)
m.dcdt = DerivativeVar(m.c, wrt = m.t)

discretizer = TransformationFactory('dae.finite_difference')
discretizer.apply_to(m, nfe=20, wrt = m.r, scheme = 'BACKWARD')

# setting initial conditions
m.c[:, 0].fix(5)

def _dae_rule(m, r, t):
    return 0 == - m.c[r, t] - m.dcdt[r, t] # note that rewriting to ODE is not desired

m.ode = Constraint(m.r, m.t, rule = _dae_rule)

sim = Simulator(m, package = "casadi")
tsim, profiles = sim.simulate(numpoints=100, integrator="idas")
```

Unfortunately, execution leads to the error message

```
DAE_Error: Currently the simulator may only be applied to Pyomo models with a single ContinuousSet
```

How so? Only `m.t` is a ContinuousSet?

Manually deleting the ContinuousSet, instead using a DiscreteSet in the first place yields the error message

```
DAE_Error: Cannot simulate a differential equation with multiple DerivativeVars
```

I don't understand. Every equation only depends on its own derivative?

Also, if i were to also discretize `m.t` can i then use any alternative solver that might work?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation on Simulator, it only supports models with 1 ContinuousSet and you have m.r and m.t. Maybe you can define a system of DAEs as a function of t, at discrete values of r, or vice versa.